# Extension for class with specific attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I would like to have an extension method for any class that has a specific attribute.

For clarification, I have to do my own serialization of objects.  But I want to only serialize objects that have this custom attribute. 
I know I can do it by inheriting from another base class,  but I already have the class attribute and I think it would be more elegant, so you could always see if an object is custom serializable.

Something like:

```
[CustomAttribut]public MyClass{} 

MyClass o = new MyClass() ;
// should only exist if class has attribut CustomAttribut. 
O.CustomSerialize();
```

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: I did not find a good solution.  Only thing was by inheriting from another class with this extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are for storing metadata - values which are static and const and known at compile time. They cannot add methods/fields to your class - interfaces are for doing that. What you can do is to create an interface:

```
public interface ICustomSerializable{
    string CustomSerialize();
}
```

Another option is to separate your class from the serialization logic. The serialization would be handled by another class. For example:

```
public class CustomSerializer{

   public string CustomSerialize(object myObject){
       // for example if object has no CustomAttribut attribute 
       // you can throw "not serializable" exception here.

   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example for this with postsharp?

Comment: PostSharp is an overkill in this case (unless you have houndreds of classes annotated with `[CustomAttribut]` and you know what you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with plain .NET. It's called AOP or [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

There are a few third party providers, like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) that offer those options.

Comment: That's unsatisfying,  not your answer,  thank you for this,  I mean that there is a restriction.  But I think I will use the Interface,  that's ok.